# Bridge wireless and ethernet to KVM

Tags: wireless, networking, ethernet, kvm-virtualization, 14.10

I've just installed a new laptop with Ubuntu 14.10 Desktop and I'd like to get try and get KVM running so that I can host a couple of guest VM's. The problem is I can't figure out how to configure the networking.

I have two problems:

1. The laptop has wireless (wlan0) and ethernet (eth0) connections and I can't be sure
   which I'll be using at any particular time.
2. The guests need to be directly accessible to other machines on the LAN.

What I think I need to do is something like disable network-manager then create a bridge that includes wlan0, eth0 and the various guest machines. I can't see how to configure this set up though and I have a feeling it won't hand over from wlan0 to eth0 and back again automatically as I change connections.

For what it's worth here's my current `interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    pre-up ip link add br0 type bridge
    pre-up ip link set dev br0 address 02:0e:40:89:3d:61
    pre-up ip link set eth0 master br0
    address 192.168.0.170
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.7
    post-down ip link set eth0 nomaster
    post-down ip link delete br0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

This configuration is basically just the one I use on my server which also runs KVM but that's simple as I just have to create a bridge in `/etc/network/interfaces` (using iproute2 rather than bridge-utils) to enslave eth0.

EDIT: I should have said that I always need to access the guest machines from the host but I only really care about other people having access when the laptop is connected via Ethernet. I would rather not have a great fuss switching over from wired to wireless but if a script is needed to handle it so be it.

EDIT 2: I've found a good solution to the problem but not to the question. Rather than create a bridge using iproute2 (or Open vSwitch) I've simply used the virbr0 bridge created automatically and switched it over to routed rather than NAT mode. This required adding a routing entry to the LAN gateway machine as the guests are now on a different subnet but that's actually better for me. If needed I think I could probably have put them on the same subnet.